# Non-Euclidean Geometrical Algebra for Real times Real?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history, real-numbers, geometric-construction, noneuclidean-geometry

This question was triggered by a series of others and reading some references:

- [Keshav Srinivasan & **Euclid**](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A71829+Euclid)
- [Eclid's Elements](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/elements.html)
- [image]

As quoted from the last reference:

GEOMETRICAL ALGEBRA.

We have already seen [ .. ] how the Pythagoreans and later Greek mathematicians
exhibited different kinds of numbers as forming different geometrical figures.
[ skip text ]
The *product* of two numbers was thus represented geometrically by the
*rectangle* contained by the straight lines representing the two numbers
respectively. It only needed the discovery of incommensurable or irrational
straight lines in order to represent geometrically by a rectangle the product of
any two quantities whatever, rational or irrational; and it was possible to
advance from a geometrical arithmetic to a geometrical *algebra*, which indeed
by Euclid’s time (and probably long before) had reached such a stage of development
that it could solve the same problems as our algebra so far as they do
not involve the manipulation of expressions of a degree higher than the
second. [ rest deleted ]

As quoted from the [second reference](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVI/propVI12.html):

Descartes began by interpreting the algebraic operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division,
and extraction of square roots as geometric constructions on lines. He represented each (positive) magnitude
by a line. Addition and subtraction were the same as Euclid’s. To add two lines, just extend one by the length
of the other. To subtract one line from another, just take the remainder after cutting it off the other.
Multiplication and division, however, were different from Euclid’s. Euclid represented the product of two lines
by a rectangle, the product of three lines by a box in space, and Euclid didn’t represent the product of four lines.
*But Descartes took the product of two lines to be another line*. [emphasis is mine] That required selecting a unit line,
that is, a line of length $1$. Then to find the product $ab$ of two quantities $a$ and $b$, he only needed to find
the fourth proportional of $1$, $a$, and $b$.

Here is the construction by Descartes (figure on the left):

[image]

After defining a unit OE and the lengths (= reals) OA and OB, in order to define the product OP, it is necessary
to draw a line OP *parallel* to EB.
Of course, there is a relationship between Euclid's and Descartes' construction: the areas of OARB and OEQP are equal.

It should be noted though, that *negative numbers* are impossible within Euclid's system, while the (Des)Cartesian
coordinate system ensures that they can be properly represented geometrically.
[Why is negative times negative = positive?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/why-is-negative-times-negative-positive)
Descartes' Euclidean Geometrical Algebra gives us a nice [proof without words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) :

[image]

**Parallel lines** seem to be essential all over the place, thus requiring an **Euclidean geometry**.
And doesn't our common [Equals sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign) not just represent two parallel $=$ lines?
So the *question is*: does there exist a multiplication of reals a la Descartes in a
**[non-Euclidean Geometrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry) Algebra** ?

Possible duplicate question, without an answer : [Geometric basis for the real numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852551/geometric-basis-for-the-real-numbers) .

Comment: Maybe the geometric-algebras tag would be appropriate? I found [Alan MacDonald's Tube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCymE67THrWoeTABxzJm1wdg) enlightening.

Comment: @P-i-: Thanks, but I'm already running out of my (5 at maximum) tags.

Comment: Worst case scenario: if such Geometrical Algebra may be considered as a _definition_ of multiplication at the real number line, then does there still exist any Real times Real, at all, with non-Euclidean geometry?

Comment: Did you check Hartshorne's book?

Comment: @MoisheCohen: ? You mean this : [Algebraic Geometry](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387902449) . While opening the book on-line ("Varieties"), I see a lot of set theory, no geometry.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Of course not, I meant "Geometry: Euclid and Beyond".

Comment: @MoisheCohen: Wow! Thanks! This is a [great reference](http://www.math.unam.mx/javier/Hartshorne.pdf) !

Comment: And it provides an answer to my question. With Euclidean Geometry, Segment Arithmetic (chapter 4) can only be accomplished _in any Hilbert plane with (P)_: the parallel axiom is essential, as I have anticipated. But I find [_Hilbert's Arithmetic of Ends_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_arithmetic_of_ends) for non-Euclidean geometry (chapter 7) rather disappointing. It seems to me that upward compatibility is violated with such an approach.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: If you turn that comment about Hartshorne's book into an anwer, then that answer will be a serious candidate for assigning the bounty. There is a real chance that the 50 rep will be in vain otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two answers to your question.

1. One answer is negative, namely, the one given in the book "Geometry: Euclid and Beyond" by R.Hartshorne, where he notes that the Euclidean parallels axiom (or its equivalent, Axiom P) is needed for **his** geometric definition of geometric multiplication.

A side remark: Hartshorne's book is one of the few places in the literature (actually, the only one apart from Hilbert that I am aware of) where, starting with Euclidean axioms one carefully builds the Hilbert plane by constructing an ordered field, etc. Other treatments start with a version of Birkhoff's axioms, which is a bit of cheating since these axioms have real numbers already present in the set of axioms (since the distance function takes values in ${\mathbb R}$).

2. On the other hand, if you allow (much more!) complicated geometric definitions of algebraic operations, then the answer is positive. You can find it in this paper by M.Kourganoff [Universality theorems for linkages in homogeneous surfaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.6815v3.pdf), where he uses certain configurations of line segments in the hyperbolic plane to define algebraic operations.